# issue testing licensing

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

Please see the graphic below...

I'm trying to set responses so that I can test my licensing logic.  But I think I have painted myself into a corner.  When I first signed up for my developer account I used my real email address of gary@deanblakely.com.  When I got my android phone I use for testing, I had to use a gmail account so setup deanblakelyuser@gmail.com and that address was used for my account on the phone.

Now if you look at the graphic right below where it says "This License Test Response will be sent to devices using gary@deanblakely.com..."

But, if I understand correctly, my account on my android test phone has to be a gmail account and the responses I choose are not working.

Then I figured I would simply change the email address on my developer account but changing it won't take.

How can I fix this situation?

[image: In app billing clip]

Comment: On your actual developer console, do you have `deanblakelyuser@gmail.com` in the Test Accounts field? It's not shown in the image. Second, you said you use that on your test phone, but later say "My acct on my test phone must be a gmail acct", which it is. Also, if the responses you choose are not working, what responses do you get? Lastly, what is your app status? Uploaded but not published? Published? Not uploaded yet?

Comment: I'm not using test accounts as they are optional.  I have not uploaded my .apk file.  I just wanted to test responses. (tried the test account field to no avail though) I always get NOT_MARKET_MANAGED back.  It appears that the problem is: Once I put an email address into the Developer Console, it can NEVER be changed.  I put deanblakelyuser@gmail.com into my account details (and it changed on my account details screen) but license testing is still looking for gary@deanblakely.com. as you can see from the graphic I posted.

Answer (score 0):

When you sign up for a Developer account, the email address you use is the main address for that account, like you guessed. The email account on the details page is mainly just for correspondence. Unfortunately, there is no way to send test responses to test devices without uploading the apk. It will only ever send it to devices linked to your main developer account.

If you just want to test responses, all you have to do is:

- Add your gmail(testing) account to the Test Accounts field
- Upload the apk to Google Play

Notice I said upload, not publish. You don't have to have a "live" application, just uploaded.

Comment: The Play team said I had to get another dev account with a gmail address so I did, this gave me a new 64 bit key, I uploaded my apk, put the same apk on my phone, set console to return NOT_LICENSED.  But I always get back NOT_MARKET_MANAGED.  So I'm stuck on that now.